# Listview item move swipe left or right

Tags: android

i want swipe list view items left or right and after swipe items are deleted 
`

```
 @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                items = new ArrayList<String>();
                items.add("arpit");
                items.add("b");
                items.add("c");
                items.add("d");
                items.add("e");
                items.add("f");
                items.add("g");
                items.add("h");
                items.add("i");
                items.add("j");
                items.add("k");
                items.add("l");


                //String[] items = { "arpit", "avninash", "lucky", "rakesh", "jitendra", "arun", "dharmendra", "amitabh", "arpit", "avninash", "lucky", "rakesh", "jitendra", "arun", "dharmendra", "amitabh" };
                listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
                listview.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
                listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "plese Move me", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        arrayadapter.remove(arrayadapter.getItem(position));
                        arrayadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });

            }

        }
        `
```

iam using this code this code creating a list view, and after click item delete item but not swipe .

Answer (score 2):

SwipeListViewTouchListener.java

```
import android.animation.Animator;
    import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
    import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
    import android.graphics.Rect;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.VelocityTracker;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AbsListView;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;

    public class SwipeListViewTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private int mSlop;
    private int mMinFlingVelocity;
    private int mMaxFlingVelocity;
    private long mAnimationTime;

    // Fixed properties
    private ListView mListView;
    private OnSwipeCallback mCallback;
    private int mViewWidth = 1; // 1 and not 0 to prevent dividing by zero
    private boolean dismissLeft = true;
    private boolean dismissRight = true;

    // Transient properties
    private List< PendingSwipeData > mPendingSwipes = new ArrayList< PendingSwipeData >();
    private int mDismissAnimationRefCount = 0;
    private float mDownX;
    private boolean mSwiping;
    private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;
    private int mDownPosition;
    private View mDownView;
    private boolean mPaused;

    /**
     * The callback interface used by {@link SwipeListViewTouchListener} to inform its client
     * about a successful swipe of one or more list item positions.
     */
    public interface OnSwipeCallback {
        /**
         * Called when the user has swiped the list item to the left.
         *
         * @param listView               The originating {@link ListView}.
         * @param reverseSortedPositions An array of positions to dismiss, sorted in descending
         *                               order for convenience.
         */
        void onSwipeLeft(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions);

        void onSwipeRight(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions);
    }

        /**
         * Constructs a new swipe-to-action touch listener for the given list view.
         *
         * @param listView The list view whose items should be dismissable.
         * @param callback The callback to trigger when the user has indicated that she would like to
         *                 dismiss one or more list items.
         */
        public SwipeListViewTouchListener(ListView listView, OnSwipeCallback callback) {
            ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(listView.getContext());
            mSlop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
            mMinFlingVelocity = vc.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity();
            mMaxFlingVelocity = vc.getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity();
            mAnimationTime = listView.getContext().getResources().getInteger(
                    android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
            mListView = listView;
            mCallback = callback;
        }

        /**
         * Constructs a new swipe-to-action touch listener for the given list view.
         *
         * @param listView The list view whose items should be dismissable.
         * @param callback The callback to trigger when the user has indicated that she would like to
         *                 dismiss one or more list items.
         * @param dismissLeft set if the dismiss animation is up when the user swipe to the left
         * @param dismissRight set if the dismiss animation is up when the user swipe to the right
         * @see #SwipeListViewTouchListener(ListView, OnSwipeCallback, boolean, boolean)
         */
        public SwipeListViewTouchListener(ListView listView, OnSwipeCallback callback, boolean dismissLeft, boolean dismissRight) {
            this(listView, callback);
            this.dismissLeft = dismissLeft;
            this.dismissRight = dismissRight;
        }

        /**
         * Enables or disables (pauses or resumes) watching for swipe-to-dismiss gestures.
         *
         * @param enabled Whether or not to watch for gestures.
         */
        public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
            mPaused = !enabled;
        }

        /**
         * Returns an {@link android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener} to be added to the
         * {@link ListView} using
         * {@link ListView#setOnScrollListener(android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener)}.
         * If a scroll listener is already assigned, the caller should still pass scroll changes
         * through to this listener. This will ensure that this
         * {@link SwipeListViewTouchListener} is paused during list view scrolling.</p>
         *
         * @see {@link SwipeListViewTouchListener}
         */
        public AbsListView.OnScrollListener makeScrollListener() {
            return new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {@
                    Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {
                setEnabled(scrollState != AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL);
            }

                @
                        Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
            };
        }

        @
                Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (mViewWidth < 2) {
                mViewWidth = mListView.getWidth();
            }

            switch (motionEvent.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {
                    if (mPaused) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    // TODO: ensure this is a finger, and set a flag

                    // Find the child view that was touched (perform a hit test)
                    Rect rect = new Rect();
                    int childCount = mListView.getChildCount();
                    int[] listViewCoords = new int[2];
                    mListView.getLocationOnScreen(listViewCoords);
                    int x = (int) motionEvent.getRawX() - listViewCoords[0];
                    int y = (int) motionEvent.getRawY() - listViewCoords[1];
                    View child;
                    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                        child = mListView.getChildAt(i);
                        child.getHitRect(rect);
                        if (rect.contains(x, y)) {
                            mDownView = child;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (mDownView != null) {
                        mDownX = motionEvent.getRawX();
                        mDownPosition = mListView.getPositionForView(mDownView);

                        mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                        mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
                    }
                    view.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
                    return true;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                {
                    if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                        break;
                    }

                    float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
                    mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
                    mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(500); // 1000 by defaut but it was too much
                    float velocityX = Math.abs(mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity());
                    float velocityY = Math.abs(mVelocityTracker.getYVelocity());
                    boolean swipe = false;
                    boolean swipeRight = false;

                    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mViewWidth / 2) {
                        swipe = true;
                        swipeRight = deltaX > 0;
                    } else if (mMinFlingVelocity <= velocityX && velocityX <= mMaxFlingVelocity && velocityY < velocityX) {
                        swipe = true;
                        swipeRight = mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity() > 0;
                    }
                    if (swipe) {
                        // sufficent swipe value
                        final View downView = mDownView; // mDownView gets null'd before animation ends
                        final int downPosition = mDownPosition;
                        final boolean toTheRight = swipeRight;
                        ++mDismissAnimationRefCount;
                        mDownView.animate()
                                .translationX(swipeRight ? mViewWidth : -mViewWidth)
                                .alpha(0)
                                .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {@
                                        Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                    performSwipeAction(downView, downPosition, toTheRight, toTheRight ? dismissRight : dismissLeft);
                                }
                                });
                    } else {
                        // cancel
                        mDownView.animate()
                                .translationX(0)
                                .alpha(1)
                                .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                                .setListener(null);
                    }
                    mVelocityTracker = null;
                    mDownX = 0;
                    mDownView = null;
                    mDownPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
                    mSwiping = false;
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                {
                    if (mVelocityTracker == null || mPaused) {
                        break;
                    }

                    mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
                    float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
                    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mSlop) {
                        mSwiping = true;
                        mListView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                        // Cancel ListView's touch (un-highlighting the item)
                        MotionEvent cancelEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(motionEvent);
                        cancelEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL |
                                (motionEvent.getActionIndex() << MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT));
                        mListView.onTouchEvent(cancelEvent);
                    }

                    if (mSwiping) {
                        mDownView.setTranslationX(deltaX);
                        mDownView.setAlpha(Math.max(0f, Math.min(1f,
                                1f - 2f * Math.abs(deltaX) / mViewWidth)));
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    class PendingSwipeData implements Comparable < PendingSwipeData > {
        public int position;
        public View view;

        public PendingSwipeData(int position, View view) {
            this.position = position;
            this.view = view;
        }

        @
                Override
        public int compareTo(PendingSwipeData other) {
            // Sort by descending position
            return other.position - position;
        }
    }

        private void performSwipeAction(final View swipeView, final int swipePosition, boolean toTheRight, boolean dismiss) {
            // Animate the dismissed list item to zero-height and fire the dismiss callback when
            // all dismissed list item animations have completed. This triggers layout on each animation
            // frame; in the future we may want to do something smarter and more performant.

            final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = swipeView.getLayoutParams();
            final int originalHeight = swipeView.getHeight();
            final boolean swipeRight = toTheRight;

            ValueAnimator animator;
            if (dismiss)
                animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight, 1).setDuration(mAnimationTime);
            else
                animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight, originalHeight - 1).setDuration(mAnimationTime);


            animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {@
                    Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                --mDismissAnimationRefCount;
                if (mDismissAnimationRefCount == 0) {
                    // No active animations, process all pending dismisses.
                    // Sort by descending position
                    Collections.sort(mPendingSwipes);

                    int[] swipePositions = new int[mPendingSwipes.size()];
                    for (int i = mPendingSwipes.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        swipePositions[i] = mPendingSwipes.get(i).position;
                    }
                    if (swipeRight)
                        mCallback.onSwipeRight(mListView, swipePositions);
                    else
                        mCallback.onSwipeLeft(mListView, swipePositions);

                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp;
                    for (PendingSwipeData pendingDismiss: mPendingSwipes) {
                        // Reset view presentation
                        pendingDismiss.view.setAlpha(1f);
                        pendingDismiss.view.setTranslationX(0);
                        lp = pendingDismiss.view.getLayoutParams();
                        lp.height = originalHeight;
                        pendingDismiss.view.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    }

                    mPendingSwipes.clear();
                }
            }
            });

            animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {@
                    Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                lp.height = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                swipeView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }
            });

            mPendingSwipes.add(new PendingSwipeData(swipePosition, swipeView));
            animator.start();
        }
    }
```

Usage

```
    // Create a ListView-specific touch listener. ListViews are given special treatment because
    // by default they handle touches for their list items... i.e. they're in charge of drawing
    // the pressed state (the list selector), handling list item clicks, etc.
    SwipeListViewTouchListener touchListener = new SwipeListViewTouchListener(
            listView,
            new SwipeListViewTouchListener.OnSwipeCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSwipeLeft(
                        ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions)
                {
                    //onLeftSwipe
                }
                @Override
                public void onSwipeRight(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) 
                {
                    //onRightSwipe

                }
            },true, // example : left action = dismiss
            false); // example : right action without dismiss animation
    listView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
    // Setting this scroll listener is required to ensure that during ListView scrolling,
    // we don't look for swipes.
    listView.setOnScrollListener(touchListener.makeScrollListener());
```

Comment: Please consider improving your answer by including explanations of how this code addresses the specific problem/requirement described in the question. Simply pasting the code without any explanation is not really helpful. Besides, the idea is to help/guide the person asking the question whilst still expecting them to try suggested solutions by themselves.

Comment: Actually,it's easy to use. I just didn't see any misunderstanding there. It's easy to use with any ListView. I'll consider your words,thanks

Answer (score 1):

well that's normal because you use the onClick method.
If you want to remove on swipe, you will have to implement the OnSwipeTouchListener :

[Android: How to handle right to left swipe gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures)

Answer (score -1):

Define a ViewPager in your layout .xml:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/example_pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height" />
```

And then, in your activity / fragment, set a custom pager adapter:

In an activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.example_pager);

    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    // pager.setOnPageChangeListener(this); // You can set a page listener here
    pager.setCurrentItem(0);
}
```

In a fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

    if (view != null) {
        PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.example_pager);

        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        // pager.setOnPageChangeListener(this); // You can set a page listener here
        pager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }

    return view;
}
```

Create our custom pager class:

```
// setup your PagerAdapter which extends FragmentPagerAdapter
class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public static final int NUM_PAGES = 2;
    private CustomFragment[] mFragments = new CustomFragment[NUM_PAGES];
    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }
    @ Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
    @ Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (mFragments[position] == null) {
               // this calls the newInstance from when you setup the ListFragment
            mFragments[position] = new CustomFragment();
        }
        return mFragments[position];
    }
}
```